# Editing a string in VB

Tags: vba

I need to get username from email address by removing the part after "@" symbol. For example,

```
Dim uemail As String
Dim uname As String

umail = email_tb.Text.ToString() 'Suppose this returns abc.xyz@pqr.com
uname = umail (and some code) 'This will return abc.xyz only
```

Comment: `uname = Split(uemail, "@")(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **VB** you can do this by using the [**Split**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method:

```
Dim umail = email_tb.Text.ToString()
Dim uname As String = Split(umail, "@")(0)
```

Using **VB.NET** you could use the [**Substring**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) and the [**IndexOf**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.IndexOf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to achieve this:

```
Dim umail = email_tb.Text.ToString()
Dim uname As String = umail.Substring(0, umail.IndexOf("@"))
```

Answer (score 1):

One efficient way, use pure string methods like `IndexOf`, `Substring` or `Remove`:

```
Dim uname = mail.Remove(mail.IndexOf("@"c)) ' check if IndexOf returned -1 first
```

You could also split by this separator:

```
Dim tokens As String() = mail.Split("@"c)
Dim uname = tokens.First()
```